# Dynamically generate Sql for variable definition and assignment for a row in a table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

For example, I have a table

```
create table T (
    A int, 
    B numeric(10,3), 
    C nvarchar(10), 
    D datetime, 
    E varbinary(8)
)
```

**Update:** This is just one of the example table. Any table can be used as input for generating the SQL string.

Is there an easy way to dynamically generate the following Sql for a row? (Any built-in function to make the Quotes, prefix easier?)

```
'declare 
    @A int = 1, 
    @B numeric(10,3) = 0.01, 
    @C nvarchar(10) = N''abcd'', 
    @D = ''10/1/2013'', 
    @E = 0x9123'
```

Comment: you need to provide more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. The closest you might get, but which still will require manual changes, is by using SQL Server Management Studio. Expand the database and the table.

Right-click the table, then select `Script table As`, `Insert To`, and then selecting a new query window. This will generate output that will give you a starting point, but it's not generating variables. You'd have to either script that yourself, or edit the generated INSERT statement.

Example code:

> INSERT INTO MyDB].[dbo].[Table1]
>              ([A]
>              ,[B]
>              ,[C]
>
> ```
> VALUES
>        (<A, int,>
>        ,<B, float,>
>        ,<C, nvarchar(10),>
>       )
> ```
>
> GO

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what specifically you are trying to achieve… There is no built in function for something like this but you can try to create one easily using query similar to this one…

```
select 'DECLARE @A int = ' + TableA.A + 
', @B numeric(10,3) = ' + TableA.B + 
', @C nvarchar(10) = N''' + TableA.C + 
''', @D = ''' + TableA.D + ''''
from TableA 
WHERE PrimaryKeyColumn = some_value
```

Just cleanup the query above and convert it into a function that returns nvarchar

If you want to dynamically generate table definitions too that’s possible too but you’ll have to use system views to create this for any given table.

Try something like this and work your way from here

```
select T.name, C.name, TY.name, C.column_id
from sys.tables T
inner join sys.columns C on T.object_id = C.object_id
inner join sys.types TY on TY.system_type_id = C.system_type_id
where T.name = 'TableName'
order by C.column_id asc
```

Comment: Any table can be used as input for generating the SQL string. Cannot hard code the types in the string.